# What's a clean way to share async function response in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have async functions similar to this:

```
class ArticleParser() {
  _title;

  async genTitle() {
    if (!this._title) {
      this._title = await takesALongTime();
    }

    return this._title;
  }
}
```

If `genTitle` is called multiple times before the first call finishes, it will call `takesALongTime` multiple times. I want all calls to `genTitle` to share the same returned promise. Is there a clean/simple way to do so?

Here's a solution that works, but it looks pretty messy:

```
class ArticleParser() {
  _title;
  _genTitlePromise;

  async _genTitle() {
    this._title = await takesALongTime();
  }

  async genTitle() {
    if (!this._title) {
      if (!this._genTitlePromise) {
        this._genTitlePromise = this._genTitle();
      }
      await this._genTitlePromise;
    }

    return this._title;
  }
}
```

Comment: What about using memoize function for this remembers the output by the argument and returns it. Here is example with ramda: `const getTitle = R.memoize(() => Promise.resolve(1));

getTitle().then(x => console.log("w", x));
getTitle().then(x => console.log("r", x));`

Comment: I ended up using a memoize decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to start waiting later so this._title will be an instance of promise. I would name it (this._title) differently in real life:

```
class ArticleParser {
  async genTitle() {
    if (!this._title) {
      this._title = takesALongTime();
    }

    return await this._title;
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Return the promise so that callers have the ability to handle both resolved and rejected promises.

Comment: Technically with the example above you can remove async/await from the function and it will have same effect for it's callers.

Comment: I ended up using a memoize decorator.